# DateTime change date value and set specific value of time in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, time

I have value of this for example

```
Dim start_time As String = 12/30/1899 8:30:00 PM
```

Then i want to change it into

```
Dim final_start_time As String = 0000-00-00 20:30:00 ' i want to come up with this value
```

or another example is

```
   Dim start_time As String =  12/30/1899 10:30:00 AM
```

to

```
Dim final_start_time As String = 0000-00-00 10:30:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your revised Question, here is some code. Revise it as necessary. I used es-ES as culture.. actually have no clue what culture that is... but on the dateformat MSDN page, that seems to generate the format you want...

```
Dim myOriginalDateTime As DateTime = Now
Dim mynewDateString As String = ""
Dim myFinalDateString As String = ""
Dim culture As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")

mynewDateString = myOriginalDateTime.ToString("G", culture)

Dim arrDateParts() As String = Split(mynewDateString, " ")

myFinalDateString = "0000-00-00 " & arrDateParts(1)

MsgBox(myFinalDateString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

And this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1(v=vs.100).aspx

You use the .tostring method, and specify a format.

Comment: yes i already read this how to convert format but how can i change by force the value of date in datetime to 0000-00-00.

Comment: Alright, you should rephrase your question then. You want to change the date part of the datetime variable, not convert it. Have you tried setting the individual parts of the datetime variable, set day, set year, set month? Alternatively, send it to a string, and manipulate the string, cut off the date part, or sobstitute it with your 0000 requirement?

Comment: Maybe share what you are trying to achieve as an end result.

Comment: yes i have try setting it by individual and my problem is how can i get the time in the string

And i already updated my post you read it again

Comment: sir @Louis van Tonder do you understand now my question?